# Fetch Cookies from Android application

Tags: android, flutter, cookies

I am trying to read the user Browser cookies through an Android mobile application (Flutter). I got to know that the cookies are also stored in the Android phones at a file location(local) `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies`.

1. How to read the cookies from this file with a Flutter Application (Android) ? (Any library or process to achieve this)
2. What is the type of data in stored in the location, (is it encrypted or plain text) ?

I have tried using "WebView", in which we have to pass the domains from which we want to fetch the cookies. But I want to fetch all the browser cookies from the mobile application across the domains.